# Display 1 from X Divs selected by CSS-Class

Tags: javascript, html, css, display

I have, on a homepage, X html div elements with X different classnames:

- class="home-1"
- class="home-2"
- class="home-3"
- class="home-4"
- etc.

My goal is, to dislpay only one of these "divs". The rest should be hidden with css.
I think, i can't do this, only with css.

what i manually can do is

```
.home-1 { display: none; }
.home-3 { display: none; }
.home-4 { display: none; }
```

So in this Case home-2 is displayed.

Of course i want that automated with javascript, can someone please help me?

that yould be very nice!

**UPDATE:**
i think i was already too tired when i wrote this question, because i forgot something important. aaarggh ;(!!

i want to use javascript to make sure that a "different" div is always displayed and the others are automatically hidden.

Comment: You could give them all another class like `.home` and then do a `display: none` on all elements with class `home`.

Comment: It's not completely clear how the div you would like to show is selected. Do you use a button, is it dependent on a get variable. How, in your example, does the "home-2" element _'know'_ it should be visible?

Comment: i thought i could show all div elements and hide all but one at random with javascript

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Its possible by `CSS`.
If you want to `hide all elements` which has class name start from **home-** and to a specific element then add **.active** class that used `display:block` property. Something like below snippet.

```css
/* Hide all .home-* elements */
[class^="home-"] { display: none; }

/* Show element which has .active class*/
[class^="home-"].active{ display: block; }
```

```html
<div class="home-1">Home 1</div>
<div class="home-2 active">Home 2</div>
<div class="home-3">Home 3</div>
<div class="home-4">Home 4</div>
```

Comment: You may wish to expand your answer to show how the `active` class might be applied, since it seems incomplete without such advice.

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica Thanks for advice:-) Now I edited and define how `active` class with work.

Comment: You're welcome, but while you're showing a runnable snippet you're not showing how the `active` class might be applied to, or removed from, any elements which the demo realistically depends on.

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica As per question there is not define any functionality like click, hover or mouseenter... event listener. for show/hide element so in this snippet simple all elements hide which has not `.active` class but if has `.active` class so this active class define display:block property for show specific element.

Comment: That's fine, though I'd argue that the question: "*[Of] course i want that automated with [JavaScript], can someone please help me?*" suggests that's an essential part of the question. This is your answer though, I'm not planning to down-vote if you choose not to.

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica I follow this one "*My goal is, to dislpay only one of these "divs". The rest should be hidden with css. I think, i can't do this, only with css.*"

Comment: Yes, that's what I am looking for, but I forgot to mention, that I always want to display a different random "div"